# How to split words in new lines?

Tags: php, regex

I have read few answers on SO, one of this suggests me to do the following but I get `array` as a result.

Basically we are on the search result and we have this:

```
$term = $_GET['s'];
```

if I do `echo $term;` I get `America 2018` while I would like to have:

```
Location: America
Time: 2018
```

I tried using explode:

```
$term = explode("\n", $term); echo $term;
```

but the result is `Array`

Comment: explode with space, and then $term[0] will be location, and $term[1] will be time

Comment: Try exploding with an empty space `explode(' ',$term); `

Comment: @Rajesh ok I see

Comment: @PankajMakwana yes I have read many of the answers, it could well be a duplicate indeed, thing is it wasn't working so I made an explicit example for my case

Comment: lol its so basic question from user with 2K rep..

Comment: @aswzen true, but I am more a front-end dev with js skills not backend and php, then again, i have tried other solutions, might well just be a little mistake i ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the snippet below to split in spaces and get the location and time:

```
$term = explode(" ", $term); 
echo "Location: " . $term[0] . "\n Time: " . $term[1];
```

Comment: nice, this works. I was about to comment that i added <br> `$term = explode(" ", $term); echo "Location: " . $term[0] . "<br>" ."Time: " . $term[1];`

Comment: Thank you, will accept in a minute `$term = explode(" ", $term); echo "<p>Location: " . $term[0] . "</p><br><p>" ."Time: " . $term[1] ."</p>"`

Answer (score 5):

No need to explode it when you can `preg_replace`. Eg:

```
$str = "America 2018";
$result = preg_replace("/([A-z]+) (\d+)/", "Location: $1\nTime:$2", $str);
echo $result;
```

**Breakdown:**

`/([A-z]+) (\d+)/`

- 1st Capturing Group `([A-z]+)`

  - Match a single character present in the list below `[A-z]+`
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `A-z` a single character in the range between `A` (index 65) and `z` (index 122) (case sensitive) matches the character literally (case sensitive)
- 2nd Capturing Group `(\d+)`

  - `\d+` matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: this works but too complicated, the other answer is simple for my case

Answer (score 3):

He want the simple way..

So this is it (just one line)

To make it like `America 2018`

```
$term = explode("\n", $term); $term = explode(" ",$term[0])[1]." ".explode(" ",$term[1])[1]; echo $term;
```

To make it like

`Location: America 
 Time: 2018`

```
$term = explode("\n", $term); $term = "Location: ".$term[0].PHP_EOL."Time: ".$term[1]; echo $term;
```

Cheer